# Could you please explain to me how to complete this truth table?

Tags: transistors, mosfet

How do I know when a short-circuit occurred based on the state of the transistors and the MOSFETs? If all the MOSFETs and transistors are OFF, does it mean that we have a high impedance in the switches?

[image]

Comment: A "short-circuit" usually means an unintended circuit path and usually due to a fault in the circuit. The words "open" or "open-circuit" and "closed" or "conducting" would be clearer. When you say "high impedance in the circuit" you need to be specific about which part of the circuit so "high impedance in the switches" might be better.

Comment: If A is low, the truth table shows QA as being on.  This is because QA is a PMOS device, so a low signal "turns it on." "Turn it on" means the source and drain are connected, like a closed switch. Now QC is *not* a PMOS - look carefully at the arrow direction.  And QB, that is an NPN transistor, similar to a NMOS. Transistors and switches both "close" their other two leads when the appropriate input signal is given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this problem looks more complicated than it actually is due to the extra qualifying "information" supplied.

In order for Y to be high it is necessary for either QA, and/or both the QB, QC pair to be switched off (high-impedance state). This is because QA is in series with the QB, QC pair thus:

```
QA           QB and QC   Y

OFF          Don't Care  HIGH
Don't Care   OFF         HIGH
ON           ON          LOW
```

Since QB and QC are in parallel the combination of these can only be off if both QB and QC are off. So overall the truth table is:

```
    QA    QB    QC    Y

    OFF   OFF   OFF   HIGH
    OFF   ON    OFF   HIGH
    OFF   OFF   ON    HIGH
    OFF   ON    ON    HIGH

    ON    OFF   OFF   HIGH
    ON    ON    OFF   LOW
    ON    OFF   ON    LOW
    ON    ON    ON    LOW
```

Comment: Please don't hand out solutions to questions that look like homework. It is much better to guide the student and help them find their own solution. We don't want this site to turn into a homework solution service.